# pytest.raises() behaving unexpectedly with custom exceptions

Tags: python, pytest

I'm adding some tests to a project using **PyTest**, and I've come across some unexpected behaviour when using **`pytest.raises()`** to assert that a custom exception has been raised.

I have a function, `camera_angle_formula_virtual()`, which invokes another function, which checks the arguments. (This slightly odd design is because there is also `camera_angle_formula_physical()` function, which needs the same checks.) If a check fails, a **custom exception** is raised. This is what the code for said functions looks like.

```py
def check_camera_index(index, number_of_cameras):
    """ Check that the index is non-negative and less than the total number of
    cameras. """
    if index < 0:
        raise WP17UtilsError("Camera index cannot be negative.")
    if index >= number_of_cameras:
        raise WP17UtilsError(
            "Camera index must be less than the total number of cameras."
        )

def camera_angle_formula_virtual(index, number_of_cameras):
    """ One of the formulae for calculating the camera angle from its index. """
    check_camera_index(index, number_of_cameras)
    return (index-1)*((2*numpy.pi)/number_of_cameras)
```

I want to write a test that checks that, if I pass in a negative index, the custom exception is raised. This is the relevant extract from my test file:

```py
with pytest.raises(WP17UtilsError):
    camera_angle_formula_virtual(-1, 4)
```

I would expect the above test to pass. However, when I run it, I get this output on the command line:

```
    def test_camera_angle_formula_virtual():
        """ Test that this function runs and produces the correct output. """
        assert camera_angle_formula_virtual(0, 4) == -numpy.pi/2
        assert camera_angle_formula_virtual(1, 4) == 0
        assert camera_angle_formula_virtual(0, 5) == -(2*numpy.pi)/5
        with pytest.raises(exceptions.WP17UtilsError):
>           camera_angle_formula_virtual(-1, 4)

tests/test_reconstruction_dir_generator.py:68: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
source/reconstruction_dir_generator.py:95: in camera_angle_formula_virtual
    check_camera_index(index, number_of_cameras)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

index = -1, number_of_cameras = 4

    def check_camera_index(index, number_of_cameras):
        """ Check that the index is non-negative and less than the total number of
        cameras. """
        if index < 0:
>           raise WP17UtilsError("Camera index cannot be negative.")
E           exceptions.WP17UtilsError: Camera index cannot be negative.

source/reconstruction_dir_generator.py:87: WP17UtilsError
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where exactly is the definition of `WP17UtilsError` coming from?  One possibility is that the actual code and the test are getting it via two different import paths, so that you're dealing with two distinct exception classes (that happen to be identical in every way, but aren't actually the same object).

Comment: This is a situation in which posting a reproducible example would be really helpful. You don't need to post all your code; just sufficient code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think @jasonharper has a good idea of what going on. For complicated reasons, I had to do something a bit out-there with the Python path. Once I untangled a couple of those knots, everything just worked.

Comment: @TomHosker would be good to see the ways how to solve this problem. Maybe you can write an answer by yourself? It would be super helpful. Looks like I have the same problem with different import paths in test and in real method

Comment: @jasonharper I assume the feature to prevent such problems should be built-in for the `pytest.raises` method. Suppose I can't use the same path for tests and src, what should I do?